# In unbiased data, RMSE and standard deviation is same?

Tags: standard-deviation, unbiased-estimator, rms

In unbiased data, RMSE and standard deviation is same?

---

Let $x_{i}$ be your true value for the $i^{th}$ data point and $\hat{x}_{i}$ the estimated value. If we assume that the differences between the estimated and true values have

1. mean zero (i.e. the $\hat{x}_{i}$ are distributed around $x_{i}$)
   (***Unbiasd***)
2. follow a Normal distribution
3. and all have the same standard deviation $\sigma$

in short:

$$\hat{x}_{i}-x_{i} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^{2}\right),$$

Then, RMSE between $x_{i}$ and $\hat{x}_{i}$ is
 $$
\text{RMSE}^2 =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\hat{x}_i)^2\,,
$$

Standard deviation of $x_{i}$ - $\hat{x}_{i}$ is
 $$
\text{SD}^2 =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}((x_i-\hat{x}_i)-mean)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\hat{x}_i)^2\
$$

So i think RMSE and SD is same in unbiased data. However, i can not be sure and find any reference.